# Convert c('a' 'c', 'b') to c('a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b') in R?

Tags: r, text, vector

Given a vector of variables, transform the vector so that each variable is repeated

For example, I could

```
sort(rep(c('a', 'c', 'b')))
```

except that I don't want to sort them; I want it to return  `c('a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'b')`

Comment: See also ?rep. Reading the help files before asking a question is considered good practice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use ?rep

```
vec <- c('a', 'b', 'c')
rep(vec, each = 2)
```